# Displaying inline within a list

Tags: html, css

I cannot get a div within a list to display inline. It seems to create a line break.

I have tried using a clear div, setting the body font-size to 0, rearranging the html and all sorts of other things to no avail.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Loy4a2st/1/

```
.guiding_more_info_button{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline;
}
.guiding_more_info{
  margin-left:3rem;
  display:none;
}


<h2>Itinerary</h2>

<li><p>Day 01 </p></li>
<li><p>Day 02</p></li>

<li>
    <p>Day 03</p>
    <div class="guiding_more_info_button">+ more info
        <div class="guiding_more_info">
            <p>more info here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>

<li><p>Day 04</p></li>
<li><p>Day 05.</p></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`P` tag `block` element, apply `p` tag to `inline`

```css
.guiding_more_info_button{
  font-family:maratExtraLightItalic;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline;
}
.guiding_more_info{
  margin-left:3rem;
  font-family:maratExtraLight;
  display:none;
}
.inline{
display:inline;}
```

```html
    <h2>Itinerary</h2>
<ul>

    <li><p>Day 01 </p></li>
    <li><p>Day 02</p></li>

    <li>
        <p class="inline">Day 03</p>
        <div class="guiding_more_info_button">+ more info
            <div class="guiding_more_info">
                <p>more info here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li><p>Day 04</p></li>
    <li><p>Day 05.</p></li>
    
</ul>
```

Comment: perfect! this was driving me insane. thanks so much.

Comment: @Archer Update my answer

Answer (score 1):

I have used your code and made some adjustments.

```css
.guiding_more_info_button {
  font-family: maratExtraLightItalic;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.guiding_more_info {
  margin-left: 3rem;
  font-family: maratExtraLight;
  display: none;
}

#day3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Itinerary</h2>

<li>
  <p>Day 01 </p>
</li>
<li>
  <p>Day 02</p>
</li>

<li>
  <p id="day3">Day 03</p>
  <div class="guiding_more_info_button">+ more info
    <div class="guiding_more_info">
      <p>more info here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <p>Day 04</p>
</li>
<li>
  <p>Day 05.</p>
</li>
```

You can view the fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/fo6ryj29/

You need to make both elements you want to show next to each other `display:inline-block`.

In your case the `div` and the `p` tag.

Comment: Answers must include code *within the answer itself*.  It's fine to also link it, but it's usually not required anyway since you can build a snippet in the answer (edit the question and click the button that looks like a document with <> on it).

Comment: I will edit my answer. I did not know that the answer requires actual code. I will remember it for the future. Thank you @Archer

Comment: No worries - have a play with the snippet editor.  It'll turn you away from jsfiddle for good! :D

Comment: I will read up about it and 'fiddle' around with it ;) @Archer

Answer (score 0):

Your html isn't written correctly. You need to wrap your `<li>`'s in the `<ul>` element for it work properly.

```css
.guiding_more_info_button{
  font-family:maratExtraLightItalic;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline;
}
.guiding_more_info{
  margin-left:3rem;
  font-family:maratExtraLight;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
    <h2>Itinerary</h2>
<ul>

    <li><p>Day 01 </p></li>
    <li><p>Day 02</p></li>

    <li>
        <p>Day 03</p>
        <div class="guiding_more_info_button">+ more info
            <div class="guiding_more_info">
                <p>more info here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li><p>Day 04</p></li>
    <li><p>Day 05.</p></li>
    
</ul>
```